# Body does not stretch to fit it's content

Tags: html, css

I searched a lot a solve for my problem but none of them is working for me. The html and the body does not stretch to fit it's content. The body height seems to be 970px. I have this code:

HTML:

> ```
>  <html>
>  <head></head>
>  <body onLoad='init()'>
>      <div id='content'>
>          <table class='pagecontent'>
>              <tr><td id='content'>
>                   some content
>                  </td>
>                   <td id='side'>
>                   some other content
>                  </td>
>              </tr>
>          </table>
>      </div>    <div id='footer'>  
>    <span class='copy'>&copy; 2014</span>    </div>  </body>  </html>
> ```

the CSS:

```
 html, body {
     width:1000px;
 } 
 html {
     display: table;
     margin: auto; }

 body{
     display: table-cell; }
 #content{  
position:relative;  
top: 468px;     
height:auto;    
min-height: 200px;  
width:1000px;

 } table.pagecontent{
border-spacing: 0px;    
width:1000px;
height:1px;
padding-bottom: 60px;

td#side{
    width:300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    border-left:20px solid black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    height:100%;


}
td#content{
    width:650px;
}
#footer{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    width:1000px;
    height:80px;
    background:url('../images/footer-back.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You've set `width` to a `px` value everywhere, and `height` to `100%`. Does that not make it clear? Also, you should add a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for such questions.

Comment: I'm new here. Sorry. The body it's not supposed to stretch to fit it's content?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, never use the same ID more than once. In your code '#content' is declared twice.
2. Do not set HTML and body tag width, better use inside body some div with class and set its width.
3. Do not use a table for page layout if it is not required by specifications.

The raw version of your code will be like in this [example](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/JbilE).

Markup:

```
<div id="layout">
    <div class="pagecontent">
        <div id="content">some content</div>
        <div id="side">some other content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">  
    <span class="copy">&copy; 2014</span>
</div>
```

Styles:

```css
.pagecontent {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#side {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  width: 650px;
}

#footer {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('../images/footer-back.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Hope it will help you.